# How to display an image that hasn't been uploaded yet?

Tags: javascript, image

at first I need to apologize for my English, I'm not a good speaker.

But here's my problem:

I made an application, where you can edit questions for a game. These questions are on a server. You download a question and they are edited locally. At the end of the session you upload your question. 
These questions should also contain images. 
Therefore I made a little form, which saves the image to an image-heap as a FormData-Object. 
This Form-Data Object is being saved into another Object.

Here's an example of how I do this:

```
var formDataTemp = new FormData();
var qcid = // given Id

if($('#editImageFileInput')[0].files[0] != undefined) {
    formDataTemp.append("img", $('#editImageFileInput')[0].files[0]);

    questionImageCache.push({
        qcid: qcid, img: formDataTemp
    });
}
```

There is more Data in the object, but i removed it to keep it simple.

There is also a list of all the questions the user has already downloaded. There he can switch from one question to another.

Now I want to display this image when the particular question comes up again. How can I do this without uploading it? Is there a way to display the image out of the javascript-object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your code works, but this is how you can display an image before it is uploaded, using `FileReader`.

Javascript:

```
function loadImg(input) {
    if (!input.files || !input.files.length) return null;

    var fReader = new FileReader();
    var img = $('#placeholder');

    fReader.onload = function(e) {
        $(img).attr('src', e.target.result);

    };

    fReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type='file' onchange="loadImg(this);" />
 <img id="placeholder" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smdqqp9t/) example.

You can take the concept from this snippet and apply it to your own project :)